# Ruby: How to Print Mirror Letter

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

In a hash, I want to be able to convert A to print Z mirroring its letter.

```
converter = {
  "A" => "Z",
  "B" => "Y",
  "C" => "X",
  "D" => "W"
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to transform the array? How to build the mapping?

Comment: What do you want to happen to inputs that aren't capital ASCII letters? So things like `'6'`, `'é'`, `'+'`, or even `'a'`?

Comment: sorry @spickermann i meant to put hash not array sorry for causing a confusion

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extend the hash you already have. Either manually or generate it once and assign to a variable.

```rb
MAPPING = Hash[("A".."Z").zip(("A".."Z").to_a.reverse)]

def mirror(letter)
  MAPPING.fetch(letter)
end
```

`fetch` will raise an Exception if a letter is not found (e.g. `mirror('a')`)

or you can do some math with the ordinality of a letter. This works because A-Z have the ordinality 65 - 90 (no gaps).

```rb
def mirror(letter)
  a = "A".ord
  z = "Z".ord
  distance = z - letter.ord
  (a + distance).chr
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are awesome!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yet Another Way In Ruby:

```
a=('A'..'Z').to_a
search_char = 'B'
result = a[-1-a.index(search_char)]
```

A far easier and faster way, with fewer error possibilities, is to transliterate the entire string instead of working one char at a time:

```
az = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
za = 'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA'
'Anywhere IT WORKS'.tr az,za      # => "Znywhere RG DLIPH"
```

Comment: `za = az.reverse`

Comment: Of course.  I used the constant for clarity and easy comparisons while testing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This code even converts all the words. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this:

```rb
def mirror str
  str.tr(('a'..'z').to_a.join, ('a'..'z').to_a.reverse.join)
     .tr(('A'..'Z').to_a.join, ('A'..'Z').to_a.reverse.join)
end

mirror "Meow" #=> "Nvld"
```

edit for not creating arrays on each invocation:

```rb
class Mirror
  LOWER = ('a'..'z').to_a.join.freeze
  UPPER = ('A'..'Z').to_a.join.freeze
  def self.mirror str
    str.tr(LOWER, LOWER.reverse)
       .tr(UPPER, UPPER.reverse)
  end
end

puts Mirror.mirror "Meow"
```

Or if you want to get fancy and just add a mirror method to all strings:

```rb
class String
  LOWER = ('a'..'z').to_a.join.freeze
  UPPER = ('A'..'Z').to_a.join.freeze
  def mirror
    self.tr(LOWER, LOWER.reverse)
        .tr(UPPER, UPPER.reverse)
  end
end

puts "Meow".mirror
```

Comment: Note that this method creates several objects (4 ranges, 4 arrays, 4 strings) every time it is called. Maybe move the strings into constants?

Comment: Yeah if this is something that is called a *lot* that is absolutely something to be concerned over. I was trying to keep it concise (and non polluting) though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `String#ord` and `Integer#chr`  methods

```
def mirror(l)
  (l.ord + (25 - ((l.ord - "A".ord) * 2))).chr
end
```

Comment: @muistooshort you get a `'j'` and an `out of range error` respectively

Comment: OP might certainly validate the input and check for other requirements (explicit or implicit) but adding more work here is not needed.

Comment: @OscarRyz : Would not work if the string is encoded in, i.e. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah, OP description of the problem is rather vague. You're right about EBCDIC, I assume these are merely string literals which in Ruby are encoded on US_ASCII prior to Ruby 2 and UTF-8 after so this should still work. In that case I think extending the map OP originally has is the best solution.

Comment: @OscarRyz: Ruby has "multiple encoding". The encoding is part of each `String` instance. Hence you can mix encodings in a program: If you read for instance data from a mainframe database and choose not to convert the encoding during reading, you will end up having some string variables being EBCDIC, while others being UTF8.

Comment: @user1934428 yup, that's what I understood on your first comment. My point is, this program seems to be used to convert string literals ( `"A"`, `"B"`, etc ) rather than data from a mainframe... or even lowercase letters (or other non ascii).  But given the OP provided such little detail the solution satisfies the requirement. I **NOT** saying you're wrong or that EBCDIC shouldn't be take into consideration for other scenarios, just pointing out the requirements are very vague.